# $$ in shell , Linux

Tags: bash, makefile

I have the following code from a make file, I know this creates bin folder in Home if that doesn't exist... but I couldn't understand what $$HOME/bin mean...

I googled and found $$ is to get the processid of the bash... but couldn't understand what $$HOME/bin mean... can someone please explain ?

```
.PHONY: home_bin
home_bin: ## Create home bin if not created
    @ if [[ ! -d "$$HOME/bin" ]]; then \
        echo "Creating $$HOME/bin"; \
        mkdir $$HOME/bin; \
        echo "✔︎ $$HOME/bin created"; \
    else \
        echo "✔︎ $$HOME/bin already created"; \
    fi
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

`make` itself performs expansion of `$`-prefixed characters; the `$$` is expanded to a single literal `$` to pass to the shell.

Consider a simple Makefile:

```
x=f

all:
        xoo=3 && echo $xoo
```

which will output `foo`, because

1. `make` expands `$x` to the single character `f`.
2. `make` passes the string `xoo=3 && echo foo` to the shell for execution

Compare with

```
x=f

all:
        xoo=3 && echo $$xoo
```

which outputs `3`, because

1. `make` expands `$$` to `$`
2. `make` passes the string `xoo=3 && echo $xoo` to the shell for execution